# Exporting an variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have one script that exports an variable and second which reads it:

script1:

```
var1=abc
export var1
./script2
```

script2:

```
echo $var1
```

Of course the variable `var1` is accessible from script2 (returns "abc")
Now when i remove the script2 call in script1 (the "export var1" line is the last one in the script1) and move the scripts calls to another script like so:

script3:

```
./script1
./script2
```

the `var1` variable isn't available in script2 anymore. Why is it like that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28489593/6378557)